# Making db.put() failsafe

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to make a db.put() operation in my Google App Engine service as resilient as possible, trying to maximize the likelihood of success even in the event of infrastructure issues or overload. What I have come up with at the moment is to catch every possible exception that could occur and to create a task that retries the commit if the first attempt fails:

```
try:
    db.put(new_user_record)
except DeadlineExceededError:
    deferred.defer(db.put,new_user_record)
except:
    deferred.defer(db.put,new_user_record)
```

Does this code trap all possible error paths? Or are there other ways db.put() can fail that would not by caught by this code?

---

Edit on March 28, 2013 - To clarify when failure is expected

It seems that the answers so far assume that if db.put() fails then it is because the datastore is down. In my experience of having run fairly high-workload applications this is not necessarily a requirement. Sometimes you run into workload-specific API bottlenecks, sometimes the slowness of one API causes the request deadline to expire in another. Even though such events have a low frequency, their number can be sizable if traffic is high. These are the situations I am trying to cover.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is the best approach - whatever caused the original exception is just likely to happen again.  What I would do for extra resilience is first load the record to be saved into memcache and in the event of an exception with the put (any exception) it could attempt a certain number of retries (for example 3) with a short sleep between each attempt.  Depending on your application this could be either a synchronous operation or using deferred tasks it could be done asynchronously using the data in memcache.
Finally I'd actually do a query on the record in the data store even if there wasn't an exception to confirm the row has actually been written.

Comment: I disagree. The exceptions this is meant to protect against are non-deterministic ones - infrastructure issues, high datastore latency, overload etc. rather than deterministic ones, such as coding errors. The taskqueue manages the probability of reoccurrence well by gracefully decrementing the retry interval. On the other hand, thanks for the tip on avoiding a double commit. In my case with streaming data duplicates don't matter, but it's certainly something to think about in general.

Comment: Ah I take your point on capturing the specific exceptions, I absolutely agree proper exception management in the case of failure should still be implemented but retry functionality with a circuit-breaker (whether via task queues or synchronous) is a common technique to manage temporary non-deterministic issues.  Just to answer the question below if there was an issue writing a single row to the datastore I woudn't assume "the datastore is just down", I would confirm that first with a sensible number of retries.  Then once that's done present the user with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i don't think that it is a good idea to try such a fallback at all. If the datastore is down, its down and youre out of luck (shouldn't happen frequently :)
Some thoughts to your code:

- There are way more exceptions that could be raised during a put-opertation (like InternalError,  Timeout, CommittedButStillApplying, TransactionFailedError)
  Some of them don't mean that the put has failed. (ie. CommittedButStillApplying just means the put-operation is **delayed**). With your approach, you would end up having that entry twice in the datastore after your deferred call succeeds.
- Tasks are limited to ~100KB (total size, not payload). If your payload is close to or above that limit, the deferred-api will automatically try to
  serialize your payload to the datastore in order to keep the task itself below that limit. If the datastore is really unavailable, this will fail, too.

So its probably better to catch datastore errors, and inform your user that his request failed.

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I'm actually not overly concerned about the 'datastore down' case, but rather of intermittent errors, as now clarified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its all good to retry, however  use exponential backoff and most important proper transaction use so that fail xoesnt end up o  a partial write.